# Buzz php HTTP-Client:setting a cookie value

Tags: php, http, cookies, buzz

is it possible to set a specific Value for the cookie, before fetching a page using the Buzz php light weight client? https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz

i want to set `splash = 0` for a specific host, to avoid a pop-up they have.

Comment: Can you post your sample code right now? That'd help a lot...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```php
$request = new \Buzz\Message\Request('GET', '/', 'domain.com');
$request->addHeader('Cookie: splash=0');
```